# Свойством какого объекта является функция getElementById()?

Tags: javascript

Свойством какого объекта является функция `getElementById()`?
В объекте `window` такой функции не нашел. В `document` и `document._proto_`  тоже не нашел.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v8sz7Lwj/ `#document -> HTMLDocument -> Document`

Comment: document.__proto__.__proto__ - тут и лежит getElementById()

Answer (score 3):

Метод `getElementById()` определен в интерфейсах [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) и [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment).

Для самого объекта document это будет прототипом второго уровня:

```js
console.log(
  document.hasOwnProperty('getElementById'), // false
  document.__proto__.hasOwnProperty('getElementById'), // false
  document.__proto__.__proto__.hasOwnProperty('getElementById')); // true

console.log(
  HTMLDocument.prototype.hasOwnProperty('getElementById'), // false
  Document.prototype.hasOwnProperty('getElementById'), // true
  DocumentFragment.prototype.hasOwnProperty('getElementById')); // true

console.log(
  document.__proto__ === HTMLDocument.prototype, // true
  document.__proto__.__proto__ === Document.prototype); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Метод getElementById существует только в контексте document

```
document.getElementById('dataKeeper')
```

Обратите внимание, что при указании идентификатора учитывается регистр символов, так например метод document.getElementById("Main") вернёт значение null вместо ссылки на элемент  по той простой причине, что символы "M" и "m" имеют различный регистр.

Answer (score -6):

Раз ты такие вопросы задаешь, надо тебе прояснить ситуацию в плане структуры объекта глобального (*BOM*), с которым ты каждый раз имеешь дело.

Нет никакого понятия "контекст" у объекта document, о котором сказано в другом ответе. *Объект-контекст выполнения кода - это объект, из которого берутся  переменные, параметры, значение свойства this и объект-стек scope для выполнения глобального кода или кода функции*. это объект-свалка. так как есть два вида кода - глобальный и код функции, то объектов-контекстов в один момент времени может быть два - *Global* и *Local*. Свойство *this* есть только у объекта-контекста *Local*, оно указывает на объект, внутри которого есть свойство, которое ссылается на функцию (то есть, *this* указывает на объект, в котором функция "лежит"). На эту тему почитай это - http://corporate.tuenti.com/en/dev/blog/functions-and-execution-contexts-in-javascript-2

Все элементы, кроме служебных, из документа хтмл преобразуются в объекты-УЗЛЫ дерева *DOM*. Есть еще дерево *CSSOM*, которое состоит из стилей, соответствующих каждому элементу *DOM*. А есть дерево *BOM* с корнем *window*, в которое "вплетаются" эти два дерева *DOM* и *CSSOM*. У каждого объекта-узла есть цепочка прототипов, по которой к объекту-узлу "спускаются" свойства (на самом деле это не обычные свойства, а имитация свойств - функции геттеры и сеттеры, которые имитируют свойство). Набор этих свойств зависит от типа объекта-узла. Типы бывают *TEXT*,*ELEMENT*,*COMMENT*, *ATTRIBUTE*, *DOCUMENT*... *window*.*document* - это объект-узел, который создается для того, чтобы прицепить в BOM дерево DOM.Про деревья DOM и CSSOM более-менее написано тут - https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/constructing-the-object-model?hl=ru

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посмотри на рисунок выше. На нем изображена НЕполная (у объекта-прототипа Node еще есть объект-прототип...) иерархия объектов-прототипов. У этого объекта-узла *window*.*document* есть объект-прототип *HTMLDocument*, у него, в свою очередь, объект-прототип - это *Document*. У *Document* тоже есть объект-прототип - *Node*. Так вот, свойство *getElementById* принадлежит объекту-прототипу *Document*. Это свойство *getElementById* "спускается" вниз по цепи прототипов к объекту document:

```
 Document--> HTMLDocument --> document
```

И становится доступно изнутри объекта *window*.*document* (через точку), как если бы реально принадлежало ему. Это и есть суть прототипного наследования свойств и методов - свойства и методы "спускаются" по цепи прототипов.

Comment: Вы вообще на какой вопрос отвечали?

Comment: я человеку в общем картину обрисовал, чтобы он разобрался. раз он такие вопросы задает тут, значит, он не понимает толком, с чем имеет дело. плюс, на сам вопрос ответил. нет толка отвечать человеку на его вопрос КРАТКО, если он картину плохо понимает. почему спросили?

Comment: Но и нет смысла отвечать *"Нет никакого понятия "контекст""* человеку, который про этот контекст не слышал. Вы вообще видели в вопросе слово "контекст"?

Comment: прочитайте внимательно второй ответ на вопрос. два ответа разных могут человека сбить с толку, кому верить - не понятно. а я еще и ссылочки кинул, чтобы не подумал человек, что я выдумал. в другом ответе неправильно написана фраза "Метод getElementById существует только в контексте document". люди часто думают (я тоже так когда-то думал), что контекст - это объект, на который ссылается свойство this. надо автору об этом сказать. не важно, что в вопросе. и не надо меня учить, как отвечать. я человеку картину обрисовал общую.

Comment: плюс, на его вопрос ответил. да и ссылки хорошие кинул того, что почитать полезно. а главное - там ПОНЯТНО рассказано более менее.  а нормальный источник найти трудно. мне бы так кто обрисовывал общие картины и источники классные подкидывал). а на минусы или плюсы мне, вообще, пофиг. пусть хоть сотню минусов нащелкают. главное, чтобы автору вопроса мой ответ помог разобраться. и чтобы человек написал "спасибо"). плюс, когда я тут ответ пишу, я повторяю, а повторение полезно для того, чтобы не забыть.

Comment: если человек про объект-контекст не слышал - самое время услышать. объект-контекст - это вещь абстрактная. можно ее и не знать, а программировать успешно. но, если человек хочет стать хорошим программистом, он должен максимально много понимать как что работает в той "штуке", с которой он имеет дело.

Comment: @Dimon в соседнем ответе под "контекстом" подразумевался не какой-то объект-контекст. Там слово "контекст" явно использовано в широком смысле "объект, в рамках чего-то что-то существует или имеет смысл"

Comment: @PashaPash тогда надо было просто написать, что метод getElementById() работает тогда, когда справа от него написать document и точку. а не мудрить с абстрактными словами, которые каждый по своему понимает. надо объяснять, а не запутывать человека непонятными словами. да и все равно написано неправильно - метод getElementById() принадлежит не объекту document, а объекту-прототипу Document из цепи прототипов объекта window.document.